# Tool for parsing nginx log

Tags: json, mongodb, nginx, hive, hdfs

I plan to migrate my request logs for web page request from mongo to nginx logs. Is there some parser/tool which I can use to parse the logs and convert to maybe JSON in  order to make them look more meaningful so that I can query on them?

Current mongo log format:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f911646e4b00a6b7b103c77"), "mUpdatedAt" : NumberLong("1334908486975"), "playerError" : "", "playerState" : "paused", "requestUuid" : "d2c8c8aa-aeab-4f87-8db0-ed699ba19249" }
```

Nginx log format:

```
115.249.242.17 - - [18/May/2012:05:40:49 +0000] "GET /flashlayer?videoId=NaN&duration=26.091&videoLoadTime=216&videoBitRate=1708 HTTP/1.1" 200 86 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0"
```

I am able to query on mongoDB and I want the same for nginx log too for which I need a simple parser to read nginx logs and convert to maybe JSON, CSV or put it in hive, HDFS.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to write such tool myself. I did that a while ago.

Comment: any pointers - what language or any link to any open source tool ?

Comment: Basic knowledge of regular expressions will allow you to do it in any language. Read about regexes.

Comment: nothing better and faster than rsyslog

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it would be much better solution for you just to configure your nginx log format to be more JSON like.
http://nginx.org/r/log_format

Comment: For an example see [aaronfeng/etc-nginx-nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/aaronfeng/3207188).

Answer (score 2):

Logstash is a great tool for doing stuff like that.  http://www.logstash.net

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use logstash with following patterns :

for access.log :

```
NGINXACCESS %{IPORHOST:clientip} - %{USERNAME:remote_user} \[%{HTTPDATE:time_local}\] %{QS:request} %{INT:status} %{INT:body_bytes_sent} %{QS:http_referer} %{QS:http_user_agent}
```

for error.log:

```
 NGINXERROR (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}[./-]%{MONTHNUM}[./-]%{MONTHDAY}[- ]%{TIME}) \[%{LOGLEVEL:severity}\] %{POSINT:pid}#%{NUMBER}: %{GREEDYDATA:errormessage}(?:, client: (?<clientip>%{IP}|%{HOSTNAME}))(?:, server: %{IPORHOST:server})(?:, request: %{QS:request})?(?:, host: %{QS:host})?(?:, referrer: \"%{URI:referrer})?
```

Answer (score 0):

NodeJs module, which you can aslo use on the command line, if you decide to install Node.
https://npmjs.org/package/ginx